# Minimum sum of n numbers with k spaces in between of a given array of size N

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic

Using dynamic programming I have to find an efficent algorithm to solve the following problem:

As input we receive an array of random numbers of size `N`, an `int k` that is the minimum distance between chosen numbers and an `int n` that is the total number of numbers we have to pick.
The goal of the problem is to find out what is the minimum possible sum of the `n` chosen numbers.
I can't figure out how to aproach this problem.

As an example if we have the following array:

```
arr = [5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 5]
N = 16
k = 4
n = 3
```

the output would be `8 (3+3+2)`, by selecting the numbers at index 2, 7 and 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have coded the solution in c++, The code is readable for the most part but if you have any ambiguity in understanding it, comment below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int number_of_elements_to_be_picked, number_of_elements, k;
int main(){
      cin >> number_of_elements >> k >> number_of_elements_to_be_picked;
      vector<int> a(number_of_elements);
      vector<vector<int> > store(number_of_elements, vector<int> (number_of_elements_to_be_picked+1));
      for(int i = 0; i < number_of_elements; i++){
              cin >> a[i];
              store[i][1] = a[i];
      }
      for(int i = 0; i < number_of_elements; i++){
              for(int j = 2; j <= number_of_elements_to_be_picked; j++){
                      if(i == k*(j-1))
                              store[i][j] = store[i-k][j-1]+a[i];
                      else if(i > k*(j-1))
                              store[i][j] = min(store[i-k][j-1]+a[i], store[i-1][j]);
              }
      }
      cout << store[number_of_elements-1][number_of_elements_to_be_picked] << "\n";
      return 0;
}
```

edit: I had incorrectly named variables, by Author's notation :- 
N = number_of_elements, n = number_of_elements_to_be_picked, k = k

Comment: Is this logic correct? dp[i][j] is the minimum possible sum till 'i' index starting from 0, 'j' being the total number of elements. It can be computed as: dp[i][[j] = min(arr[i] + dp[i-m][j-1]) where m >= k and m <= i for the example dp[16][3] would be the answer.

Comment: I think the case which you are saying is already getting covered! We Know that the value of m <= i that's the reason we are taking min(dp[i-k][j-1]+a[i], dp[i-1][j]), this already takes into consideration that the value at i-k is already minimum for j-1 values. You can even try running the debugging the code by adding print statements for better insight.

Comment: your solution doesn't work https://ideone.com/5Ozd58 as I think you are not making sure that you select exact 'n' elements.

Comment: I had made a mistake in naming the variables check again.

Comment: did you run your program? Also, explain your algorithm a bit with respect to how are you filling the matrix?

Comment: Okay, I will proceed with the explanation of the algorithm.
The int dp[N][n] is our matrix, the N represents total numbers in the array and n represents the total numbers that are to be picked.

Comment: Now consider for an index i in the array and j the number of elements picked up to index i, this would inculcate two scenarios whether we are picking the number at index i or not that's where the minimum comes in the picture that is if until index i-1 and j, the values is less than the value that would be taken by including index i it would be much more beneficial to just directly take that number.

Comment: The only part where my program would fail is when N < k*n

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191196/discussion-between-kauzijoshi-and-newbie-old).